# is_trivially_copyable/constructible etc support of clang++ and g++

Tags: gcc, c++11, clang, type-traits, libstdc++

iso 20.9.4.3 Type Properties [meta.unary.prop] are not fully supported by g++'s libstdc++-v3 ; e.g.:

```
wget -O - https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits 2>/dev/null | grep "still unimplemented"


  // is_trivially_copyable (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_constructible (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_default_constructible (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_copy_constructible (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_move_constructible (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_assignable (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_copy_assignable (still unimplemented)
  /// is_trivially_move_assignable (still unimplemented
```

and thus, at least as far as I understand it, clang builds based on gcc installations will inherit this lack of implementation; at least the

```
clang version 3.5.0 (212792)
```

I built just some hours ago with

```
g++ (Debian 4.8.3-3) 4.8.3
```

(but which somehow uses gcc-4.9 includes nevertheless) does not support those type traits mentioned.

---

But somehow Coliru 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

has a clang installation, which, if invoked with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -lsupc++  && ./a.out
```

compiles e.g. this

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

example without complaints.

So there must be method to compile or setup clang, at least on Linux with headers which  support also those type traits yet unimplemented by libstdc++.

---

In addition, llvm has this

http://libcxx.llvm.org/type_traits_design.html

summary compiled, but I have no clue how to use those "__" intrinsics; they apparently do neither live in std:: nor ::;

--

*So - **how to setup or configure recent llvm/clang on Linux so that clang++ has the most of those set of type traits available?***

**Addendum** in respose to a comment

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors test_type_traits.cxx -lm  -lsupc++
```

test_type_traits.cxx:1:10:

fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.

Comment: There exists a STL called libc++, tried that? It is "clangish". Otherwise clang will use libstdc++. You can actually see coliru using it.

Comment: It exists, but doesn't even have <iostream> on my installation.

Comment: "libc++ is a 100% complete C++11 implementation on Apple's OS X." If it didn't have <iostream> it would not be 100% complete. Maybe coliru is compiling on Apple, but in any case, you can see on the command line, that it is linking with it.

Comment: I had already posted the coliru command line. I've added the output of that command invoked locally now. And what may work on OS X is off-topic here; pls attend my question.

Comment: But you pointed me in the right direction; see my answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simply has to install libc++ **completely**

Here it is
http://libcxx.llvm.org/

That built and installed like a charm and now clang indeed has those type traits when invoked like

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ <other arguments>
```